# how to merge two dictonaries in python with union of values if the keys do exist in both

Tags: python

how to merge two dictonaries in python with union of values if the keys do exist in both. Each dictionary has values as list.

I have three dictionaries:

```
   d1 = {"KEY1": [1, 2, 3]}
   d2 = {"KEY1": [2, 3, 4]}
   d3 = {"KEY2": [1, 2, 3]}
```

how could I merge then so if:

```
   merge(d1,d2) --> {"KEY1": [1, 2, 3, 4]}
   merge(d1,d3) --> {"KEY1": [1, 2, 3],"KEY2": [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: What have you tried? (There is no built-in support for this kind of merge.)

Comment: You can check, for each key in d1, if it exists in d2 (with d2.get(key)); if it does, you can merge the 2 values lists with list(set(list1)|set(list2)). Note that this method doesn't keep the orders of the lists.

Comment: @Swifty nor does it account for either list containing duplicates.

Comment: From OP's example I inferred duplicates are unwanted.

Answer (score 1):

define a merge function (here as lambda function):

```
merge = lambda x,y: {v:list(set(x.get(v, []) + y.get(v, []))) for v in x.keys() | y.keys()}
```

output:

```
    merge(d1,d3)
    {'KEY2': [1, 2, 3], 'KEY1': [1, 2, 3]}

    merge(d1,d2)
    {'KEY1': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: It doesn't take care of repeated values. But you can modify it using my comment above.

Comment: did not noticed it removed the duplicate, now fixed, :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For such a specific kind of dictionary merging, you have to create a custom merge function. Something like this is probably a good start:

```
def merge(d1, d2):
    merged = {}
    for k in d1:
        if k in d2:
            merged[k] = sorted(list(set(d1[k] + d2[k])))
        else:
            merged[k] = d1[k]
    for k in d2:
        if k not in merged:
            merged[k] = d2[k]
    return merged

d1 = {'KEY1': [1, 2, 3]}
d2 = {'KEY1': [2, 3, 4]}
d3 = {'KEY2': [1, 2, 3]}

print(merge(d1, d2))
print(merge(d1, d3))
```

Output:

```
{'KEY1': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
{'KEY1': [1, 2, 3], 'KEY2': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the expected output by using `**dictionary` which treats the elements of this iterable as positional arguments to any function call.

```
def merge(a,b):
    try:
        return {**{**a,**b},**{k: set(set(v).union(b[k])) for k, v in a.items()}}
    except:
        return {**a,**b}


print(merge(d1,d2))
print(merge(d1,d3))
```

Output:

[image]